# Side Menu in Ionic 2 to be opened permanently when resolution more than 768px.

Tags: angular, ionic2

In Ionic 2. I have disabled the closing of side menu while selecting the menu item with commenting this.menu.close() in openPage(). but when I'm clicking or tapping on outside the side menu the side menu is closing. I need the side menu to be opened when resolution is more than 768px.

[image]

But when tapping or clicking outside the side menu closes the side menu.
[image]

How can I prevent the closing of side menu when tapping or clicking outside the side menu in Ionic 2?

Comment: Would there be any progress on this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can do this straightforwardly. What I would do to have this behavior is to use a component wrapper inside the menu content and use this same wrapper inside the `<ion-content>` if the resolution is higher than some value (with an `*ngIf`).

Could it be convenient in your case?

**EDIT : I posted an example of what I proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856823/ionic-2-side-menu-always-visible/40859962#40859962).**

Comment: Actually I tried by changing some logic in node_modules/ionic-angular/components/men/menu.js and prevented sidenav from closing but   I am unable to perform any events or actions in the main content. So I reverted. Actually when sidenav is opened we cannot perform any action until sidenav is closed.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said that I was not sure you can do this "straightforwardly". Could my idea be a solution for you?