# Ionic 2 side menu always visible

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2

I have a requirement to always display side menu and hide menu icon in the title bar when my app is loaded in tablet devices. I tried a lot but no success. Can anyone though some light here?

Comment: please provide some details of what you're asking. some code at least would help. see [mcve] for some more info on getting better answers

Comment: I don't have any sample code as my code is standard Ionic 2 side menu code. My question is if we can modify Ionic code or add some extra code wihch can override the behaviour of the Ionic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Ionic version 2.2.0 there is an out of the box solution for this, called split pane:

```
<ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu [content]="myNav"></ion-menu>
    <ion-nav #myNav main><ion-nav>
</ion-split-pane>
```

More information [here](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-2-0-is-out/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `showWhen` and `hideWhen` properties. Documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/show-hide-when/ShowWhen/). Indeed, there is a `tablet` [platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/). But you will be confronted with this : when a user clicks outside a menu, he closes it.

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815028/side-menu-in-ionic-2-to-be-opened-permanently-when-resolution-more-than-768px/40817226#40817226), what I would do to have a such behavior is to use a component wrapper inside the menu content and use this same wrapper with a `showWhen` property on `tablet` in the `<ion-content>`.

**EDIT : Adding code to illustrate the solution I proposed.**

## Menu always visible on some platforms *behavior like* example

### Test environment :

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 3.19
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

### App

./src/app/app.component.html :

```
<ion-menu
    [content]="root"
>
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>
                Menu
            </ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <sitemap-component
            hideWhen="tablet, phablet"
        >
        </sitemap-component>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav
    #root
    [root]="rootPage"
>
</ion-nav>
```

./src/app/app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';


@Component({
  templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

./src/app/app.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { SitemapComponent } from '../components/sitemap/sitemap.component';
import { ContentComponent } from '../components/content/content.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SitemapComponent,
    ContentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SitemapComponent,
    ContentComponent
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### Main content (platform independent)

./src/components/content/content.component.html :

```
<p>
    Here is the main content.
</p>
<button
    ion-button
    menuToggle
>
    Menu
</button>
```

./src/components/content/content.component.scss :

```
content-component {
}
```

./src/components/content/content.component.ts :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component(
    {
        selector    : 'content-component'
      , templateUrl : 'content.component.html'
    }
)
export class ContentComponent
{
    constructor()
    {
    }
}
```

### Sitemap (in menu or in main content part, according to the platform)

./src/components/sitemap/sitemap.component.html :

```
<p
    hideWhen="tablet, phablet"
>
    Here is the menu content on a platform that is neither a tablet nor a phablet.
</p>
<p
    showWhen="tablet, phablet"
>
    Here is the menu content on a platform that is a tablet or a phablet.
</p>
<ion-list
>
    <ion-item
        *ngFor="let item of item_array"
    >
        {{item}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

./src/components/sitemap/sitemap.component.scss :

```
sitemap-component {
}
```

./src/components/sitemap/sitemap.component.ts :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component(
    {
        selector    : 'sitemap-component'
      , templateUrl : 'sitemap.component.html'
    }
)
export class SitemapComponent
{
    item_array =
    [
        "foo"
      , "bar"
    ]

    constructor()
    {
    }
}
```

### Home page

./src/pages/home/home.html :

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Ionic Blank
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content
    padding
>
    <div
        showWhen="tablet, phablet"
    >
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col
                width-20
            >
                <sitemap-component>
                </sitemap-component>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col
                width-80
            >
                <content-component>
                </content-component>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </div>
    <div
        hideWhen="tablet, phablet"
    >
        <content-component>
        </content-component>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

./src/pages/home/home.scss :

```
page-home {
}
```

./src/pages/home/home.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor()
    {
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please throw me some code sample? I tried using menu's setOpen method which keep the menu always visible but I cannot click on anything on the content page. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have no `tablet` to test the code I posted on a real device but in Chrome Emulator, this seems to work.

Comment: Many thanks for complete code. I much appreciate your help. However I am having issues running this code

Comment: Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'content]' is not a valid attribute name.
    at BrowserDomAdapter.setAttribute (\C:\Projects\Test\IonicResponsiveMenu\IonicResponsiveMenu\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\browser_adapter.js:264:90)

Comment: Ionic Framework: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic Native: 2.2.3
Ionic App Scripts: 0.0.45
Angular Core: 2.1.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.1.1
Node: 7.1.0
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36

Comment: It seems to be an uncorrelated error. May I suggest you to : first `ionic start` a new `blank` project, then serve this project in order to check that all is valid with your ionic environment and finally just copy/paste my code at proper destinations?

Comment: Many thanks. I did not use blank template. I was under impression that this code is based on sidemenu template hence, I was trying that. Many thanks for your help. It works as charm. :)

Comment: Glad this helped you :)!